# Scroll faster in datePickerView resulting in incorrect date display

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uidatepicker

I am using a UIDatePickerView inside a UITextField. On clicking the textField, the datePickerView is shown. For reference, the following is the set of print statements (along with the one setting the datePickerView's date) and its output:

```
print(dateOfBirthTextField.text)
print(dateOfBirthTextField.datePickerView.date)
dateOfBirthTextField.datePickerView.setDate(dateOfBirthTextField.text!, animated: false)
print(dateOfBirthTextField.text)
print(dateOfBirthTextField.datePickerView.date)
```

Output:

```
Optional("Apr 24, 1998")
2016-07-26 18:30:00 +0000
Optional("Apr 24, 1998")
1998-04-23 18:30:00 +0000
```

I have placed the above code in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate method. Ignore the date format and locale. The problem is, while selecting the date.

1. I scroll very fast, and before the scroll completes, I resign the first responder (either by clicking the next/done in toolbar or clicking elsewhere).
2. And then I click the same textField - the date shown in the textField is the same as what was there already, but the datePickerView shows a different date even though I have changed it manually.

For example, I click the textField, scroll the year, and then click the done button before the scroll completes. Now, I click the same textField, the datePickerView shows "Apr 24 1969". That's the first issue (it should have been "Apr 24 1998").

Now, I change the month. The datePickerView shows "May 24, 1969", but the textField shows "May 24, 1998". So the year field gets stuck at some year.

Is there any way to solve it?

I have subclassed UITextField to behave like a UIDatePicker.

```
class DateSelectionTextField: UITextField {
    var datePickerView: UIDatePicker!
    var dateString: String? {
        willSet {
            self.text = newValue
        }
    }
    func createPickerView(dateFormatter: String) {
        datePickerView = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectZero)
        if dateFormatter == "MM/dd/yyyy" {
            datePickerView.minimumDate = displayDateForDateOfBirth("01/01/1940")
            datePickerView.maximumDate = displayDateForDateOfBirth(displayStringForDateOfBirth(NSDate())!)
        } else if dateFormatter == "yyyy/MM/dd" {
            datePickerView.minimumDate = displayDateForTransaction("01/01/1940")
            datePickerView.maximumDate = displayDateForTransaction(displayStringForTransaction(NSDate()))
        }
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = .Date
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateValueChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.inputView = datePickerView
    }
    func dateValueChanged() {// Date action for date picker view
        dateString = displayStringForDateOfBirth(datePickerView.date)
    }
}
```

The display functions are for displaying in certain date formats and would not cause the problem. So I have not included them here. I have called createPickerView from the viewDidLoad method of a viewController where I have used the textField.

Comment: can you add more codes on how you handle the datepicker value changed. From there you could know why your textfield value not following your datepicker

Comment: What did you meant by 'inside a UITextField'. If you want you can set Date picker to inputView of the text field. e.g.  textField.inputView = datePicker; Then use UITextField delegate methods to populate and set date picker values. eg. datePicker.date = DateInTheTextField at textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate method

Comment: @RJE, Yeah. That's what I did. Since I have to use it in many places, I have put it in the textField subclass - DateSelectionTextField - for a common usage.